# A fair die is rolled 10 times. Define N to be the number of distinct outcomes. Find the mean and standard deviation of N.

Tags: probability, combinatorics, expectation, dice

A fair die is rolled 10 times. Define N to be the number of distinct outcomes. For example, if we roll (3, 2, 2, 1, 4, 3, 1, 6, 2, 3) then N = 5 (the distinct outcomes being 1, 2, 3, 4 and 6). Find the mean and standard deviation of N.
Hint: Define $I_j =
  \left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
 1 & \text{if outcome j appears at least once} \\
 0 & \text{otherwise}
 \end{array} 
\right.$
    and $j=1,...,6$. Then $N=\sum_{j=1}^{6} I_j$ where $I_1,...I_6$ are dependent.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: The hint gives a pretty immediate tool to use to calculate the mean.  Have you at least figured that part out yet?  Remember that the expected value is *linear*., i.e. $E[N]=E[\sum I_j] = \sum E[I_j]$.  What is the expected value of $I_1$ for starters?

Comment: As for the second part, $stddev(N)=\sqrt{Var(N)}$ and note that $Var(N)=E[N^2]-E[N]^2 = E[\sum\sum I_jI_k] - \mu^2$ and you can break the doublesummation into those terms where $j=k$ and those terms where $j\neq k$ and split the expected value up again via linearity.  What is $E[I_1\cdot I_2]$?  What is the probability that $1$ appears at least once and $2$ appears at least once?

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! I'm just confused intuitively how you get the sum to be a probability?

Comment: Is $I_1=6$? Because there are 6 ways to get the case where $N=6$.

Comment: $ I_1$ is a random variable which takes the value of 1 with probability $ p $ and zero with probability $1-p $. Neither it nor it's expected value is equal to six.  I'll add a longer answer when I get home

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH!! I'm so confused, I'm going to keep thinking about it but I'm lost.

Comment: @JMoravitz AHH okay so would it make sense for the $P(I_1)=1-(5/6)^{10}$ so then the expected value of $E[I_1]=1*(1-(5/6)^{10})$ so then $E[N]=6*(1-(5/6)^{10})$ I'm still rather confused about the standard deviation part though, if you could possibly shed light on that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*For the sake of brevity, I will assume that you already know the definitions of random variables, expected value, and standard deviation and will not formally define these terms.  For a formal definition, seek out any textbook on the subject.*

Our problem asks us to find the mean (*expected value*) and standard deviation (*square root of variance*) for the random variable $N$ which represents the total number of unique results from a throw of ten (*presumably standard fair six-sided*) dice.  Clearly $N$ is an integral random variable which takes the values $0,1,2,\dots,6$ with corresponding probabilities $p_0,p_1,p_2,\dots,p_6$ respectively.

One (*naive*) approach to the problem would be to try to calculate each of $p_0,p_1,\dots$ and use the formula $E[N] = 0\cdot p_0+1\cdot p_1+2\cdot p_2+\dots+6\cdot p_6$, call this result $\mu$, and then continue to calculate $Var(N) = (0-\mu)^2\cdot p_0+(1-\mu)^2\cdot p_1+\dots+(6-\mu)^2\cdot p_6$.  Although this would work, this is a horribly difficult and tedious approach and is not at all recommended.  We don't actually care about finding the exact values of each of these probabilities if all we want to know about is the expected value and variance.  Instead, we approach in a much smarter and more efficient way which is alluded to in the given hint.

By letting $I_j$ represent the *Indicator Random Variable* which takes the value of $1$ when result $j$ was included in the results of the ten thrown dice, and takes the value of $0$ otherwise.  We notice then that $N$ could be represented by adding together $I_1,I_2,\dots,I_6$.  We choose to do this because calculations using indicator random variables is much easier than otherwise since they only ever take the values of zero or one.

I am happy to see from the comments that you have realized the strength of this for finding the expected value of $N$.  Indeed, by the linearity of expectation and the symmetry of the problem we have $E[N] = E[\sum\limits_{j=1}^6 I_j] = \sum\limits_{j=1}^6 E[I_j] = 6\cdot E[I_1] = 6\cdot Pr(I_1=1) = 6\cdot (1-(\frac{5}{6})^{10})$

---

Continuing the problem to find the Variance (*and taking the square root of this result to find the standard deviation*), we remember that from basic properties one finds that $Var(N)=E[N^2]-(E[N])^2$

We know how to deal with the second term from our earlier work in the previous part, but we now need to look at $N^2$ and see how it acts.  Continuing to use the indicator random variables, we see that

$N^2 = (I_1+I_2+\dots+I_6)^2=(I_1+I_2+\dots+I_6)\cdot(I_1+I_2+\dots+I_6)$

$=I_1(I_1+I_2+\dots+I_6)+I_2(I_1+I_2+\dots+I_6)+\dots+I_6(I_1+I_2+\dots+I_6)$

As alluded to in my initial comments above, by expanding this completely and not adding any like-terms together, we are left with $36$ terms total in the above expression.  By splitting these up into two categories, those which involve only one subscript and those which involve two subscripts, we have $6$ terms of the form $I_j^2$ and $30$ terms of the form $I_jI_k$ with $j\neq k$.  (*I specify without adding like-terms together to make calculations more transparent since you have $I_1I_2$ as well as $I_2I_1$ appearing once each*)

We have as a result $E[N^2]=E[(\sum\limits_{j=1}^6 I_j)^2] = E[\sum\limits_{j=1}^6\sum\limits_{k=1}^6 I_jI_k] = E[\sum\limits_{j=1}^6 I_j^2 + \sum\limits_{(j,k)\in \{(x,y)\in [6]^2~:~x\neq y\}} I_jI_k]$

$=\sum\limits_{k=1}^6 E[I_1^2] + \sum\limits_{(j,k)\in \{(x,y)\in [6]^2~:~x\neq y\}} E[I_1I_2] =  6\cdot E[I_1^2]+30\cdot E[I_1I_2]$

Now, notice that $I_1^2 = I_1$.  Why?  Well, whenever $I_1$ takes the value of $1$, $I_1^2$ will also take the value of $1$ since $1^2=1$ and whenever $I_1$ takes the value of $0$, $I_1^2$ will also take the value of $0$ since $0^2=0$.  Incredibly convenient!  So, we have already done the necessary calculations to find this part.

Now... we look a bit more closely at $I_1\cdot I_2$.  Since $I_1$ and $I_2$ are indicator random variables, you have $I_1\cdot I_2$ will take the value of $1$ if and only if both of $I_1$ and $I_2$ each took the value of $1$ as well and take the value of zero otherwise.  That is to say $I_1\cdot I_2$ is also an indicator random variable!  Specifically:

$I_1\cdot I_2 = \begin{cases} 1&\text{if}~1~\text{and}~2~\text{both appeared in the results of the ten thrown dice}\\0&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$

So, $E[I_1\cdot I_2] = Pr(I_1\cdot I_2 = 1) = Pr(\text{both}~1~\text{and}~2~\text{appear})$

I will leave the rest to you to complete now, but all that remains should be a routine calculation perhaps involving the use of inclusion-exclusion and arithmetic putting all of the gathered information together into a final answer.

Comment: Thank you so much!! This is much clearer than the examples from my textbook and other things I looked for online!

Comment: @Wren I'm glad you find it helpful.  The linearity of expectation is an incredibly powerful tool and is made only more powerful when you use this method of rewriting an integral random variable as the sum of indicator variables.  It is worth keeping in your bag of tricks which you are developing over the course of your studies and will particularly come in handy in future courses such as [Probabilistic Methods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probabilistic_method).

Comment: @JMoravitz Let me point out that all of these have simple closed forms, see below.

Answer (score 2):

Supposing that the fair  die has $n$ sides and is  rolled $m$ times we
get for the  probability of $k$ distinct outcomes  by first principles
the closed form

$$\frac{1}{n^m} \times
m! [z^m] {n\choose k} (\exp(z)-1)^k.$$

Let us verify that this is a probability distribution. We obtain

$$\frac{1}{n^m} \times
m! [z^m]
\sum_{k=0}^n {n\choose k} (\exp(z)-1)^k.$$

Here we  have included the  value for $k=0$  because it is  a constant
with respect  to $z$ and  hence does  not contribute to  $[z^m]$ where
$m\ge 1.$ Continuing we find

$$\frac{1}{n^m} \times
m! [z^m] \exp(nz) = 1$$

and the sanity check goes through. Now for the expectation we get

$$\mathrm{E}[N] =
\frac{1}{n^m} \times
m! [z^m]
\sum_{k=1}^n k {n\choose k} (\exp(z)-1)^k
\\ = \frac{n}{n^m} \times
m! [z^m]
\sum_{k=1}^n {n-1\choose k-1} (\exp(z)-1)^k
\\ = \frac{n}{n^m} \times
m! [z^m] (\exp(z)-1)
\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} {n-1\choose k} (\exp(z)-1)^k
\\ = \frac{n}{n^m} \times
m! [z^m] (\exp(z)-1) \exp((n-1)z).$$

This is

$$\frac{n}{n^m} \times
(n^m - (n-1)^m) = n \left(1-\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)^m\right).$$

This goes to $n$ in $m$ as  it ought to. For the next factorial moment
we obtain

$$\mathrm{E}[N(N-1)] =
\frac{1}{n^m} \times
m! [z^m]
\sum_{k=2}^n k (k-1) {n\choose k} (\exp(z)-1)^k
\\ = \frac{n(n-1)}{n^m} \times
m! [z^m]
\sum_{k=2}^n {n-2\choose k-2} (\exp(z)-1)^k
\\ = \frac{n(n-1)}{n^m} \times
m! [z^m] (\exp(z)-1)^2
\sum_{k=0}^{n-2} {n-2\choose k} (\exp(z)-1)^k
\\ = \frac{n(n-1)}{n^m} \times
m! [z^m] (\exp(z)-1)^2 \exp((n-2)z).$$

This is

$$\frac{n(n-1)}{n^m} (n^m - 2(n-1)^m + (n-2)^m)
\\ = n(n-1) \left(1-2\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)^m 
+ \left(1-\frac{2}{n}\right)^m \right).$$

We get for the variance

$$\mathrm{Var}(N) = \mathrm{E}[N^2] - \mathrm{E}[N]^2
= \mathrm{E}[N(N-1)] + \mathrm{E}[N] - \mathrm{E}[N]^2$$

which yields

$$n^2 \left(1-2\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)^m 
+ \left(1-\frac{2}{n}\right)^m \right)
\\ - n  \left(1-2\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)^m 
+ \left(1-\frac{2}{n}\right)^m \right)
+ n \left(1-\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)^m\right)
\\ - n^2 \left(1-2\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)^m 
+ \left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)^{2m} \right)
\\ = n^2 \left(\left(1-\frac{2}{n}\right)^m 
- \left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)^{2m} \right)
+ n \left(\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)^m 
- \left(1-\frac{2}{n}\right)^m \right).$$

The absolute value of the two  differences of terms that are geometric
in $m$  with positive  common ratio  less than one  is bounded  by the
maximum of  these two, which  vanishes in  $m$ and hence  the variance
goes to zero for $n$ fixed and $m$ going to infinity.

The  queried standard  deviation  is then  given by  the  root of  the
variance.

Here is some Maple code to explore these numbers.

```
ENUM :=
proc(n, m)
    option remember;
    local ind, data, gf;

    gf := 0;

    for ind from n^m to 2*n^m - 1 do
        data := convert(ind, base, n)[1..m];
        gf := gf + v^nops(convert(data, `multiset`));
    od;

    gf/n^m;
end;

EN_PROB := (n, m) -> subs(v=1, ENUM(n, m));

EN_FM1 := (n, m) -> subs(v=1, diff(ENUM(n, m), v));
EN_FM2 := (n, m) -> subs(v=1, diff(ENUM(n, m), v$2));

FM1 := (n, m) -> n*(1-(1-1/n)^m);
FM2 := (n, m) -> n*(n-1)*(1 - 2*(1-1/n)^m + (1-2/n)^m);

EN_VAR := (n, m) ->  - EN_FM1(n, m)^2
+ subs(v=1, diff(v*diff(ENUM(n, m), v), v));

VAR := (n, m) ->
n^2*((1-2/n)^m-(1-1/n)^(2*m)) + n*((1-1/n)^m-(1-2/n)^m);
```

**Addendum.**  As  pointed   out  by  @JMoravitz  we   may  need  some
clarification  of  the  reasoning   by  which  the  probabilities  are
obtained.   Note that  $k$ distinct  outcomes first  of all  require a
choice of these $k$ values from the $n$ possibilities, for a factor of
${n\choose  k}.$ Now  we need  to match  up each  of these  $k$ values
(think of them as listed sequentially from smallest to largest) with a
subset of the $m$ rolls which may  not be empty (this is what prevents
double counting  here).  This  yields the labeled  combinatorial class (labeled means EGFs)

$$\def\textsc#1{\dosc#1\csod}
\def\dosc#1#2\csod{{\rm #1{\small #2}}}
\textsc{SEQ}_{=k}(\textsc{SET}_{\ge 1}(\mathcal{Z}))$$

or alternatively (compare to Stirling numbers of the second kind)

$$\textsc{SEQ}_{=k}(\textsc{SET}_{=1}(\mathcal{Z})
+ \textsc{SET}_{=2}(\mathcal{Z})
+ \textsc{SET}_{=3}(\mathcal{Z}) + \cdots).$$

We get the generating function

$$\left(z+\frac{z^2}{2!}+\frac{z^3}{3!}+\frac{z^4}{4!}+\cdots\right)^k
= (\exp(z)-1)^k$$

and may then continue as before.

**Addendum II.** Another combinatorial class we can use here is

$$\textsc{SEQ}_{=n}(\mathcal{E} + 
\mathcal{U}\times\textsc{SET}_{\ge 1}(\mathcal{Z})).$$

This gives the EGF

$$G(z, u) = (1+u(\exp(z)-1))^n
= \sum_{k=0}^n {n\choose k} u^k (\exp(z)-1)^k.$$

On evaluating

$$\left. \frac{\partial}{\partial u} G(z, u) \right|_{u=1}$$

using the second form we get the  same sum as before. We can also give
an alternate evaluation

$$\frac{1}{n^m} \times m! [z^m]
\left. \frac{\partial}{\partial u} G(z, u) \right|_{u=1} 
= \frac{n}{n^m} \times m! [z^m] \exp((n-1)z) (\exp(z) - 1)
\\ = \frac{n}{n^m} \times m! [z^m] (\exp(nz) - \exp((n-1)z))
= \frac{n}{n^m} (n^m - (n-1)^m)
\\ = n \left(1-\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)^m\right).$$

For the next factorial moment we need another derivative which is

$$n(n-1)(1+u(\exp(z)-1))^{n-2} (\exp(z)-1)^2.$$

Set $u=1$ to get

$$n(n-1) \exp((n-2)z)(\exp(2z)-2\exp(z)+1).$$

Extracting coefficients now yields

$$\frac{n(n-1)}{n^m} \left(n^m - 2 (n-1)^m + (n-2)^m\right)$$

and the  rest is as in  the first version.  Note that we get  a faster
enumeration  routine   if  we   admit  the  classification   from  the
introduction.  The result is midway between enumeration and the closed
form and is shown below.

```
with(combinat);

ENUM2 :=
proc(n, m)
    option remember;
    local gf, part, psize, mset;

    gf := 0;

    part := firstpart(m);

    while type(part, `list`) do
        psize := nops(part);
        mset := convert(part, `multiset`);

        gf := gf + binomial(n, psize)
        *m!/mul(p!, p in part)
        *psize!/mul(p[2]!, p in mset)*v^psize;

        part := nextpart(part);
    od;

    gf/n^m;
end;
```

Comment: Thank you for clarifying the variance aspect! I was actually still struggling with that part.

Comment: Thank you. Sometimes it is useful to work with variables rather than constants to discern the salient features of a problem.

Comment: Adding some information on *why* that is the correct probability distribution would be helpful.  I, for one, do not see it immediately but that may simply be a result of which method I usually employ (*I use generating functions less frequently*).  @Wren if you were still having an issue completing the task using my answer, you could always ask for further clarification on my post.

Comment: @JMoravitz Ahh thanks! I didn't want to bother you too much--I'm new to stackexchange and didn't know the proper etiquette--I'll keep that in mind for next time!

Comment: @JMoravitz I respect your work. What I have here is combinatorial rather than probabilistic. We use the simplest possible definition of probability, number of favorable cases divided by total number of cases. I will add some commentary.