# Probability of getting at least 1 6 AND at least 1 5 when rolling 10 die.

Tags: probability

So I know how to find the classic probability of at least 1 6, when rolling 10 die. Its just $$1-P(\text{no } 6) = \left(1-\frac{5}{6}\right)^{10}.$$ How would I do this for both 5 and 6? Right now I am thinking to do $$1-P(\text{no } 5)-P(\text{no } 6)-P(\text{no } 5  \text{ and no } 6).$$ Is this correct?

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2140363/a-fair-die-is-rolled-10-times-define-n-to-be-the-number-of-distinct-outcomes-f/2141307#2141307 as this was the remaining missing information that I left to the user at the time to complete.

Comment: You’re on the right track, but you have to *add* the probability of “no 5 and no 6” back in because you’re counted it twice in the previous two terms.

Answer (score 3):

This is almost correct.  Remember your Inclusion-Exclusion principle.  $\Pr(A\cup B)=\Pr(A)+\Pr(B)-\Pr(A\cap B)$, or rearranged we have $\Pr(A\cap B)=\Pr(A)+\Pr(B)-\Pr(A\cup B)$

Let $A$ be the event that a $5$ was among those that were rolled.  Let $B$ be the event that a $6$ was among those that were rolled.

Then, $A\cap B$ is the event that at least one five and at least one six were rolled.

$\Pr(A\cap B)=\Pr(A)+\Pr(B)-\Pr(A\cup B)$

Now, notice $\Pr(A)=1-\Pr(A^c)$, $\Pr(B)=1-\Pr(B^c)$, and $\Pr(A\cup B) = 1-\Pr((A\cup B)^c)=1-\Pr(A^c\cap B^c)$

$A^c$ represents the event that no fives were rolled, which you correctly calculate the probability of above as $\Pr(A^c)=(\frac{5}{6})^{10}$ implying $\Pr(A)=1-(\frac{5}{6})^{10}$

What does $A^c\cap B^c$ represent as an event?

> The event that simultaneously no fives and no sixes were rolled

What is $\Pr(A^c\cap B^c)$?

> $(\frac{4}{6})^{10}$

What then is $\Pr(A\cup B)$?  What then is the probability $\Pr(A\cap B)$?

> $\Pr(A\cup B)=1-\Pr(A^c\cap B^c) = 1 - (\frac{4}{6})^{10}$

$~$

> $\Pr(A\cap B) = \Pr(A)+\Pr(B)-\Pr(A\cup B) = \dots$

Comment: I see. Essentially what amd commented above, I was double counting one of the conditions. Thank you so much!