# Rolling a fair $k$-side die $n$ times, what is the expected number of distinct outcomes?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, random-variables, expectation, conditional-expectation

For example, if I roll a $6$ side die $4$ times, and get $\{1,1,3,5\}$. The number of different outcomes would be $3$. So if rolling a fair $k$-side die $n$ times, what is the number of different outcomes I would get in expectation?

The problem looks like coupon collector, but it is asking the destination of a random walk instead of number of steps.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Maybe of interest also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2140363/a-fair-die-is-rolled-10-times-define-n-to-be-the-number-of-distinct-outcomes-f

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $X$ be the number of different numbers rolled, and write
$$ X=\sum_{i=1}^kX_i$$
where $X_i$ is the indicator random variable of the event that the $i$th number is among the numbers rolled. Then
$$ \mathbb{E}[X]=\sum_{i=1}^k\mathbb{P}(X_i=1)=k\mathbb{P}(X_1=1)$$
and
$$ \mathbb{P}(X_1=1)=1-\Big(\frac{k-1}{k}\Big)^n$$
and so
$$ \mathbb{E}[X]=k\Big(1-\Big(\frac{k-1}{k}\Big)^n\Big)$$

Comment: Sanity check: this is $< k$ (as it should), and if one takes $n\ll k$ rolls then indeed the expectation is $\ll k$ (and, as one would... expect, is $\approx n$).